# How can I relax the X security constraints for the jenkins daemon?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, android, xorg, daemon, xhost

It works fine on the commandline, when I do

```
xhost +  
su - jenkins  
emulator -avd myAVD.avd
```

but

```
emulator -avd myAVD.avd
```

executed by jenkins daemon fails with

```
"SDL init failure: No available video device"
```

**How can I relax the X security constraints for the jenkins daemon,

so that it can do `emulator -avd myAVD.avd` without failing ?**

Comment: If you don't get any satisfying answer you might get one at http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason you get the error is that `emulator` does not know *where* your display is. X11 programs use the `$DISPLAY` environment variable to discover the X11 server location, and the way most daemons are started they do not receive the environ variable. (Most daemons do not [and should not] need X11 to run.)

You will need to find a way to pass the current value of `$DISPLAY` to the daemon – note that it *may* change between logins.

As for security, **do not** ever use `xhost +` – it gives full access to *everyone*<sup>1</sup>. Instead, give the other account access to your *Xauthority* data.

```
$ xauth extract /dev/stdout $DISPLAY | su -c "xauth merge /dev/stdin" jenkins
```

---

One possible way to automate all of this is to put a few commands in your `~/.xprofile`... you will need ACL support enabled for the following to work:

```
# your .xprofile
if [ "$DISPLAY" ]; then
    touch /tmp/jenkins-display
    setfacl -m u::rw,u:jenkins:r,g::-,o::- /tmp/jenkins-display
    { echo $DISPLAY; xauth nextract /dev/stdout $DISPLAY; } > /tmp/jenkins-display
fi
```

and make an `emulator-wrapper` script for running the `emulator` tool:

```
#!/bin/sh
# a wrapper script for 'emulator'
{ read -r DISPLAY; export DISPLAY; xauth nmerge /dev/stdin; } < /tmp/jenkins-display
exec emulator "$@"
```

Somewhat ugly.

---

<sup>1</sup> "Everyone" usually means any user who can run programs on the computer – but if your X11 server is listening for TCP connections, it would mean "the whole Internet", although this is uncommon in modern distros.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/systemInfo
shows all environment variables for the jenkins daemon process,
and $DISPLAY is missing.